# Pandas inconsective True value row to find each segement's min()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

pandas df has column boolean column 'delta' which includes rows not all true or false. I am looking to find the minimum values of close in each segment where delta is True. need result with date index as well.

```
          close     delta
date        
2020-07-15  5.27    True
2020-07-16  5.25    True
2020-07-17  5.10    False
2020-07-20  5.08    False
2020-07-21  5.33    True
2020-07-22  5.15    True
2020-07-23  5.11    True
2020-07-24  5.04    True
2020-07-27  5.06    True
2020-07-28  5.03    False
2020-07-29  5.00    True
2020-07-30  4.95    True
2020-07-31  4.97    True
2020-08-04  5.05    True
2020-08-05  5.17    False
2020-08-06  5.11    True
2020-08-07  5.06    True
2020-08-10  5.33    True
2020-08-11  5.38    False
2020-08-12  5.60    True
2020-08-13  5.76    True
2020-08-14  5.89    False
```

Comment: you can use some thing like df.min(delta= True)

Comment: this is https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html documentation, i got the idea from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case do `cumsum` then `groupby`

```
df.loc[df.delta,'close'].groupby((~df.delta).cumsum()).min()
Out[74]: 
delta
0    5.25
2    5.04
3    4.95
4    5.06
5    5.60
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: is a way also to display date index?

Answer (score 1):

there is a min function, use somethig like this:

```
df['close'].min(delta=True)
```